# Firebase Cloud Messaging Service suddenly stops receiving mesages

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

My application receives push notifications after some event on the server.

Everything works fine, except in the case when there is a lot of events happening one-by-one inside a small interval of time.

After this, the case application suddenly stops receiving FCM remote notifications at all.

From the backend side everything is okay.

It is receiving a success response from Firebase.

The Firebase token on the device is also okay because of the app receiving the notification from the Firebase console.

Comment: Ensure Server side API-Key active on firebase console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Notification message or Notification message with optional data payload. 
With section

```
 "notification":{
  "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
  "body":"great match!"
}
```

A flood  of  Data  messages  will  be  stopped, only  lots  of  notification  messages inside  small  interval  of  time can  be  received. It is  not  documented  anywhere, found  the  solution  after  a  huge amount of  different  experiments

Answer (score 2):

You should probably whitelist your backend server. You can do this using Google Admin APIs by adding the IP address of the server which delivers push notifications to the GCM server. This might have been added as an added security measure to prevent abuse.

Comment: Yep,this sounds right - please explain why this is required or useful. And in what cases it is required.